# Downloading songs from YouTube, which codec to use?

Tags: audio, youtube, music, codec

I want to mass download songs from YouTube using cli app called spotdl, I'm  confused as it offers audio in different codecs, there is

1. Opus at ~120kbps-149kps,48KHz
2. AAC at ~133kbps-192kbps,44.1KHz and
3. MP3 at about >200kbps,44.1KHz

I understand Opus is latest code, and MP3 is the oldest, but I do not know how they compare in terms of quality.

So my question is: which codec should I use if

1. I have good speed internet and do not want to sacrifice musical quality at all
2. Slower internet, but I'm willing to loose a little musical quality?

Comment: Your internet speed is irrelevant as you always have to download the original audio first, before you can convert it.

Comment: Unless I'm misinformed, youtube does not stream original audio, it streams encoded audio. I'm downloading the streaming audio, not ripping from source